# Ruby code to check if website has a sitemap or not

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sitemap, typhoeus

I am developing an application in rails which requires checking whether a sitemap of the entered website's URL exists or not? For Eg if a user enters http://google.com then it should return "Sitemap present".I have seen for solutions that usually websites have either /sitemap.xml or /sitemap at the end of their URL.So i tried putting a check for this using typhoeus gem, checking  response.code for the URL(like www.google.com/sitemap.xml OR www.apple.com/sitemap) that if it returns with a 200 or 301, then sitemap exists, else not.But i have found that some sites return a 301 even if they dont have a sitemap, they redirect it to their main page(For Eg http://yournextleap.com/sitemap.xml), hence i don't get a conclusive result.Any help would be really great.
Here is my sample code to check for sitemap using typhoeus :

```
# the request object
request = Typhoeus::Request.new("http://apple.com/sitemap")

# Run the request via Hydra.
hydra = Typhoeus::Hydra.new

request.on_complete do |response|
  if response.code == 301
   p "success 301" # hell yeah
   elsif response.code == 200
    p  "Success 200"
   elsif response.code == 404
.   puts "Could not get a sitemap, something's wrong."  
    else
    p "check your input!!!!"
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The HTTP response status code 301 Moved Permanently is used for
>   permanent redirection. This status code should be used with the
>   location header. RFC 2616 states that:
>
> ```
> If a client has link-editing capabilities, it should update all references to the Request URI.
> The response is cachable.
> Unless the request method was HEAD, the entity should contain a small hypertext note with a hyperlink to the new URI(s).
> If the 301 status code is received in response to a request of any type other than GET or HEAD, the client must ask the user before redirecting.
> ```

I don't think its fair for you to assume that a 301 Response indicates that there was ever a sitemap. If you're checking the existence of a sitemap.xml or a sitemap directory then the correct response to expect is a 2XX.

If you're insistent on assuming that a 3XX request indicates a redirect to a sitemap, then follow the redirect and add logic to check the url of the page (if its the homepage) or the content of the page to see if it has XML structure.

Answer (score 0):

Sitemap may also be compressed to `sitemap.xml.gz` -- so you may have to check for that filename too. Also, it may have an index file that points to many other sub sitemaps which also may be named differently.

For examples in my project I have:

```
sitemap_index.xml.gz 
  -> sitemap_en1.xml.gz (english version of links)
  -> sitemap_pl1.xml.gz (polish version of links)
  -> images_sitemap1.xml.gz (only images sitemap)
```

Websites ping search engines with those filenames, but sometimes they also may include them in the `/robots.txt` file, so you may try hunting for them in there. For example http://google.com has this at the end of their file:

(See how weird sitemaps' names can be!)

```
Sitemap: http://www.gstatic.com/s2/sitemaps/profiles-sitemap.xml
Sitemap: http://www.google.com/hostednews/sitemap_index.xml
Sitemap: http://www.google.com/ventures/sitemap_ventures.xml
Sitemap: http://www.google.com/sitemaps_webmasters.xml
Sitemap: http://www.gstatic.com/trends/websites/sitemaps/sitemapindex.xml
Sitemap: http://www.gstatic.com/dictionary/static/sitemaps/sitemap_index.xml
```

About 301: you may try spoofing as a Google Bot or other crawler. Maybe they redirect everyone except robots. But if they redirect everyone, there's nothing you can really do about it.

Comment: I got your point,thanks, but is there any other way of getting a conclusive result for my case?

Comment: If by your case you mean 301 response code, then, not really. It's just like @sunny-j explained. You may _guess_ of course there's something they don't want to share with normal users, so _maybe_ it's a sitemap.

Comment: Thanks.Yeah i understood about 301 response code from @Sunny's reply. By my case i mean is there any alternative solution for this problem?

Comment: If site has a sitemap like `a54gf343.xml` and doesn't include it in the `robots.txt` file, then I suppose there's no way to discover it, unless you're a search engine they pinged. You may hunt for normal names like sitemap.xml, sitemap.xml.gz, sitemap_index... etc. or check in `robots.txt` to discover usual sitemaps - but you already know that.